# Magento : display layout without css js or html nodes

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

first of all i have a phtml page like this :

```
<div>
...
</div>
<form>
...
</form>
```

what i wanna do is display this phtml just like this shema and not inside html and body nodes

is there any possibility to do this ?

Comment: But why? Is it not an option to include it in a document that has the proper structure?

Comment: i have my reason to do this 
http://contacts-extensions.magentoext.com/icontacts view the source of this i wanna do like this

Comment: Well, you can do that by just outputting the HTML code and hope that browsers will display it correctly (most probably will). It's not guaranteed though. A valid HTML document needs a `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>`. Still, why do you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: to display it in modal box using javascript

Comment: That's likely possible, depending on the modal box you are using. Can you clarify what you want to do using which product and where you are stuck?

Comment: i found it <block type="core/template" name="root" .../> by changing name to "root" :D now i need to display it in modal box using javascript